# how to change source code in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv, machine-learning

I am trying to change the opencv svm predict function by passing an extra variable called std::pair & ,so that I can get the class label as well as decision function value from that function. I have change the source code in /home/rakib/opencv-2.4.9/modules/ml/src/svm.cpp and also add the function declaration in header file. The problem is that when I rebuild opencv I got the following error.

```
Scanning dependencies of target opencv_python
[ 75%] Building CXX object modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o
In file included from /home/rakib/opencv-2.4.9/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:1129:0:
/home/rakib/opencv-2.4.9/build/modules/python/pyopencv_generated_types.h: In function ‘PyObject* pyopencv_CvSVM_predict(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/home/rakib/opencv-2.4.9/build/modules/python/pyopencv_generated_types.h:4878:5: error: ‘pair_double_and_double’ was not declared in this scope
     pair_double_and_double labConCount;
     ^
/home/rakib/opencv-2.4.9/build/modules/python/pyopencv_generated_types.h:4878:28: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘labConCount’
     pair_double_and_double labConCount;
                            ^
/home/rakib/opencv-2.4.9/build/modules/python/pyopencv_generated_types.h:4885:40: error: ‘labConCount’ was not declared in this scope
         pyopencv_to(pyobj_labConCount, labConCount, ArgInfo("labConCount", 0)) &&
                                        ^
make[2]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python/CMakeFiles/opencv_python.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Though I want to change the c++ code of opencv but it some how related to python opencv interface so far I understood.

So any help to fix this problem is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the source and would like to see the change in python as well, you'll also need to regenerate the python bindings.
See [here](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/da/d49/tutorial_py_bindings_basics.html) for more details.

Comment: I am glad to get so quick reply. actually I don't need anything that is related to python. I just want it for my C++ project. So any other suggestion !!

Comment: No problem, you may need to explicitly set the python arguments in CMake to nothing so that it doesn't compile for python.

Comment: I think the argument would be -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by using cmake -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=OFF